# How to stop an app from Requesting Attention/Alerting/Appearing in the Task Manager of multiple virtual desktops in KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, desktop, plasma5, virtual-desktop

I commonly have this issue with both Unity and KakaoTalk - the apps constantly do this "alert" or "Request Attention" state where they appear orange and become visible on the task bar of all virtual desktops:

[image: KakaoTalk requesting attention in KDE]

How can I disable this? I checked the Task Manager settings, KWin rules, switching to Icons-only mode, but haven't found something that works.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want to remove is a feature of the "*task manager*" widget.

There is a much more simplistic "task-manager-like" plasma widget named "*Window list*" which does not implement this feature.

- Right click on the plasma dock and enter the *edit mode*,
- Click on the *Add Widget* button,
- Scroll down the list of widgets until you find the *Window list* widget,
- Drag and drop it somewhere into your dock

And, if it fits your needs, you can then remove the *task-manager* widget.

Beware, unlike the *task-manager* widget, this *window list* does not come with any pre-installed launcher, you might want to add them individually into your dock after the removal of the task manager widget.

Comment: Window List works, but it's too simplistic as it only shows the current active window instead of all of them. I appreciate the answer though <3

Comment: @Dr-Bracket : ??? mine is showing everything opened. One app (window opened) on each one of my four virtual desktops (spectacle on fourth) all shown in the list (apart from spectacle (which is normal)  https://i.imgur.com/5BMfQHE.png

Comment: Task Manager shows all open windows side by side which is what I want (it's only the "Alert" I want to rid of)